# Continue running WebApp with "Screen off/Background" on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, webspeech-api

**I am making a WebApp that uses [WebSpeech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) for Text to Speech.**

> The problem I am facing is that whenever the screen goes off or
> browser window is switched, particularly on mobile devices, the speech
> synthesis is just stopped. When the text to be read takes longer time,
> the device screen times out, the reading progress is lost, which is
> really bad UX.

The basic synthesis controller is is created by `const synth=window.speechSynthesis;` which is attached to window.

I have overcome with a dirty workaround of keeping the screen on by using [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js), which essentially plays a video in the background to keep the device awake.

However, I noticed that some music players can play audio when browser is minimised and even when the screen is turned off. Example: [wynk.in](http://wynk.in)

**Is it possible to achieve the same in my case? Any inputs on how is it done in music apps? Is attaching to anything other than window going to help?**

1. Link to my WebApp: https://vivek-nexus.github.io/tts.html
2. Link to my JS Script: https://vivek-nexus.github.io/js/tts.js

PS: I am a beginner in JavaScript :p

Comment: did you finally find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Oh yes, I did. Not a clean solution though. I just play a tiny invisible video file on infinite loop on the page, to prevent the screen from turning off. I pause and play it, as I need to wakelock, so that it does not drain the page resources. https://github.com/vivek-nexus/listen/blob/main/components/Player.jsx#L285 Turns out that some music from that video file was actually useful for a good UX in my use case, but you can choose a soundless video file as well. Try it here: https://vivek-nexus.github.io/listen